# RouteConfig & culture in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I am trying 2 different approaches to set up my routes in my multilingual website.

With the RouteConfig.cs, the following works fine in both languages:

```
    route = routes.MapRoute(
      name: "DataVesselRegister",
      url: "{culture}/Data/staff",
      defaults: new { action = "Index", controller = "Staff", culture = defaultCulture.Name },
      constraints: new { culture = new SiteCultureConstraint(AppConfig.Sitename) }
    );
    // A route value determines the culture of the current thread
    route.RouteHandler = new MultiCultureMvcRouteHandler();
```

However, when I try to do the same thing  using the Route Attribute instead:

```
  [Route("{culture}/data/staff")]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
```

The site remains in English which is its default language.

Why can't I achieve the same behaviour with Route Attribute in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action method signature does not include the culture variable. You must change your action method to pass in the variable from the URL.

```
public ActionResult Index(SiteCultureTypeName culture)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Tried that but I got an error on SiteCultureTypeName not being recognized. Do I need to install some packages?

Comment: The type would be the same type as defaultCulture within your 'defaults' in the first code snippet. SiteCultureTypeName was just a placeholder.